# Why does the presence of a property in a TypeScript interface affect type narrowing via asserts, and how can I get it to work correctly?

Tags: typescript, types, assertion, typescript-generics

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=33&ssc=1&pln=34&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gWzHAdhFwByBDB0C8UA5AIJFQA+xAQuVUTHcQCJEDcAUB6JFAGIBXADZD4SVOmABnKIQDeHKEqgBtAApQAliliJkaDDjwBdAFxQ5AX06Xu4aGP2SZhNdgBOwTdiEAeQSKOEhhSAHycEAAeyJ5QPA56wdIA6prAABa+ACpQUcDoACYyQQZYuBChsrripTIAZBaKyupaOllmFtYcXRza+e4AZtgAxtAAohhpIKkZ2bmR+ShF1U6G5ZV5hTITXqCNylAA9IfDibXmJc4zmVnhTUoA5hDAlxi+AKrzi8uvZXihAAoUOVzO8AJQXM5XNI3UIqd7GTgHKTPX4fL5bFZJIwVIEgqDvAA0UFONUk5gCoihIXhxghUGwUhRnhkGU0MnZUB2U2ucyo7zuB3cEAQcAAbhA0Z9NktitS-rjgXhQfTGczpHF0pzOdzQLyxpFhkIBAUINliQK7rYOEa1VzJnsFAcwAIAEZCTTDEnyqSQskhKpWTj3KAu92eqBPF7yuYyn7ynGApUQcxZMH7A7KYXAATuHRsqQAOlJq2kKmTiJD1udbo9XpR0f9wFjC0xv0TeOVUCyxJLSQpwipTakKnaqqZEBZmu12wd0xh2UqTszSgLxZ95fKxiqfdKSOU1eUYbrUGFoolaJycblTY7ydT4-VrK1HNnuxAGZXa93zk3JiqAhLBAAzaBABT7kotjWgMgHDF4qBQDBKAAIwAh4DzmLqID0lhvKkEQoTLko6GFg2vwAkQtDElYYIQaezy5jo6FsEchxQMh5hSOkcDCAUXLuO43RcEhcGaAhSEAExoe4GH2u+OFznhZCESGJFkfKFFkNRli0apMmFme4qShp+G6UKDF5gyMksccUASeY6FQFxPFCHxrrjIpC5oBK7ihEJHBAA) (uncomment the commented line in the interface to see the error but also note how the type of `arg` on the final line of `fun2` changes with and without the commented line)

```
type ComponentName = 'A' | 'B' | 'C' | 'D';

type FullComponents = {
    [P in ComponentName]: {};
}
type Components = Partial<FullComponents>;
export type ComponentsWith<T extends ComponentName> = Components & {
    [P in T]: {};
};

interface EntityWith<T extends ComponentName> extends Entity {
    //components: ComponentsWith<T>;
    getComponent<U extends ComponentName>(name: U): ComponentsWith<T>[U];
    setComponent<U extends ComponentName>(name: U, component: FullComponents[U]): asserts this is EntityWith<T | U>;
    removeComponent<U extends ComponentName>(name: U): asserts this is EntityWith<Exclude<T, U>>;
}

class Entity {
    public components: Components = {};
    public getComponent<T extends ComponentName>(name: T) {
        return this.components[name];
    }
    public setComponent<T extends ComponentName>(name: T, component: FullComponents[T]): asserts this is EntityWith<T> {
        this.components[name] = component;
    }
    public removeComponent<T extends ComponentName>(name: T): asserts this is Entity {
        this.components[name] = undefined;
    }
}
```

Given the above setup code, I would expect the following function:

```
function fun1(arg: Entity): EntityWith<'A'>{
    arg.setComponent('B', {});
    return arg; // 1: should Err
}
```

to result in an error (as the return types of `getComponent()` should be incompatible?), however it does not.  For some reason, `EntityWith<T>` is compatible with `EntityWith<U>` for any `T` and `U` I've tried (even `never`)

Since I've had repeated issues with the way TypeScript handles function signatures (very poorly), my intuition was that making `Entity.components` public and including it in the interface might help.  Since Typescript correctly handles `ComponentsWith<T>` (at least in all cases I've tested), having a property should (I assumed) fix the issue.

While this fixed my initial issue, it somehow broke the `asserts` on my assertion function signatures.

The following:

```
function fun2(arg: Entity): EntityWith<'A'>{
    arg.setComponent('A', {});
    arg.removeComponent('A');
    return arg; // 2: arg should be EntityWith<never>
}
```

previously resulted in the value of arg being in order: `Entity`, `EntityWith<'A'>`, `EntityWith<never>`, but after adding the `components` property to the interface, `removeComponent()` no longer narrows the type at all, resulting in it remaining as `EntityWith<'A'>`.

Can someone explain why this occurs (to further my understanding of TypeScript's type system) and if possible, offer some way to get this to work as desired?

Edit: So the main issue certainly seems to be that assertion functions should not broaden a type.  I'd still love an answer as to why in the initial code, they do in fact broaden the type, but perhaps that's a bug?  And I'd love some kind of workaround if one exists (I've tried asserting `never` instead of broadening, but `never` is assignable to all types so this doesn't help.  And I can't remove `removeComponent` from `EntityWith<T>` since it then improperly extends `Entity`

Edit2: I've been thinking about this and barring a bug in TypeScript, the only explanation I can think of is that without the `components` property, `EntityWith<T>` is always considered a narrowing of any other `EntityWith<U>` regardless of what `T` and `U` are.  Repeated `set` and `remove` `Components` correctly change the type (until you uncomment `.components`.  I tested and `EntityWith<T> & EntityWith<U>` does not resolve or combine in any way, so it isn't that the types intersect in some way.  Is this a bug or design limitation of how TypeScript handles functions? And adding a property somehow gives me the "correct" behavior?

Comment: Not sure the oslution, but the problem is that `EntityWith<T>` extends `Entity`. So casting to `EntityWith<T>` narrows the type. But going the other way broadens the type. And typescript doesn't forget what it's inferred so far.

Comment: @AlexWayne Ah so asserting `is Entity` for example, should not affect any subtype of `Entity` since it already has the narrowed type?  but then why does it broaden the type in the inital code (with `components` commented out)?  why is this only sometimes true?

Comment: The main issue with your code is that, all these generic variables `T` in each method, they‘re independent to each other. They’re not the same type, you just name them the same. Try rename any one of them, no error will throw. Plus, I think you’re expecting a bit too much from a static typing engine. What you want is almost runtime type checking. What you intent to archive is not possible in TS.

Comment: @hackape I'm not at all sure what you mean regarding independent `T`s,  They're dependent or independent in exactly the places I need them to be.  Most of what I want to achieve works, and I have runtime type checking.  The only way to get an `EntityWith<T>` is via methods which have runtime effects (and in my actual code, via some other runtime type guards).  What I want seems to be simply a way for an assertion function to broaden a type (or a workaround for such), which is well within the scope of a static typing engine in general, if perhaps not the current version of TypeScript.

Comment: Maybe I’m wrong…I’m not sure now either. Let me get some sleep and check tomorrow with a clearer mind. Apology if I bothered you.

Comment: @hackape No worries, I just don't think the overall structure of the generics is the issue since i'ts only the `removeComponent` function that doesn't work.  I only included the others in order to illustrate the problem.  Sleep well :)